# Structuring firebase database, dependency on two variables

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, structure, relationship, nosql

I'm having some trouble structuring my database. 
Currently I have users and groups structured as following:

```
-groups
    -groupId
         -groupname: "...."
         -users
              -userId: true


-users
  -userId
       -username: "..."
       -groups
            -groupId: true
```

Now I want to add variables that are dependent on both groups and user. I tried making another tree called `groupUser` containing both a `groupId` and `userId`, but it's hard to query on two conditions with Firebase. So what would be the best way to structure the database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not hard to query on two conditions as long as the structure fits the query! Can you elaborate a bit on what you are querying for? The question is a bit open ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure your data like so:

```
{
    groups: {
        groupIdOne: {
            groupname: "...",
            users: {
                userIdOne: true
            }
        }
    },
    users: {
        userIdOne: {
            username: "...",
            groups: {
                groupIdOne: true
            }
        }
    },
    groupUsers: {
        groupIdOne: {
            userIdOne: {
                //data for group users
            }
        }
    },
    //and/or
    userGroups: {
        userIdOne: {
            groupIdOne: {
                //data for user groups, same as above   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way if you have a group id and a user id you just query that node directly by doing something like `.child('groupUsers').child(groupId).child(userId)`